# C# Program Crashes When No Number In TextBox

Tags: c#, validation

I have a WPF Application in C# and for one of my textboxes, the input is taken and then automatically converted(Celsius to Fahrenheit). When you input a number, it works fine, but then once all the digits of the inputted number are removed, the program crashes. I guess this is because the input format is 'invalid' because it's just trying to convert nothing?
I'm stumped on how to work around this, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

This is my code within the application:

```
private void tempC_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    tempC.MaxLength = 3;
    Temperature T = new Temperature(celsius);
    T.temperatureValueInCelcius = Convert.ToDecimal(tempC.Text);
    celsius = Convert.ToDecimal(tempC.Text);
    T.ConvertToFarenheit(celsius);
    tempF.Text = Convert.ToString(T.temperatureValueInFahrenheit);
}
```

and this is the code from the API I have created:

```
public decimal ConvertToFarenheit(decimal celcius)
{
    temperatureValueInFahrenheit = (celcius * 9 / 5 + 32);

    return temperatureValueInFahrenheit;
}
```

Comment: Try using Decimal.TryParse.

Comment: If the conversion is merely done to display in the UI (has no business need), then look into using a `ValueConverter`.

Answer (score 5):

You should call the method [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) that tries to convert the value and signal if the conversion is not possible.

```
if(Decimal.TryParse(tempC.Text, out celsius))
{
   // Value converted correctly
   // Now you can use the variable celsius 

}
else
   MessageBox.Show("The textbox cannot be converted to a decimal");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void tempC_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Decimal temp;
    if (!Decimal.TryParse(out temp, tempC.Text))
       return;
    ...
```

Comment: Aren't you missing an out parameter there?

Comment: Ack.  Yes.  `TryParse` is such an abomination.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you really don't like it :-)

Comment: @Steve: In retrospect, all of the `try` methods should probably return a `Tuple<T, bool>` but Tuples didn't exist back then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void tempC_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(tempC.Text = "")
           return;
        tempC.MaxLength = 3;
        Temperature T = new Temperature(celsius);
        T.temperatureValueInCelcius = Convert.ToDecimal(tempC.Text);
        celsius = Convert.ToDecimal(tempC.Text);
        T.ConvertToFarenheit(celsius);
        tempF.Text = Convert.ToString(T.temperatureValueInFahrenheit);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Decimal.TryParse`
Here is some examples

```
string value;
decimal number;

// Parse a floating-point value with a thousands separator. 
value = "1,643.57";
if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out number))
   Console.WriteLine(number);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse '{0}'.", value);      

// Parse a floating-point value with a currency symbol and a  
// thousands separator. 
value = "$1,643.57";
if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out number))
   Console.WriteLine(number);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse '{0}'.", value);   

// Parse value in exponential notation. 
value = "-1.643e6";
if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out number))
   Console.WriteLine(number);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse '{0}'.", value);   

// Parse a negative integer value. 
value = "-1689346178821";
if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out number))
   Console.WriteLine(number);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse '{0}'.", value);   
// The example displays the following output to the console: 
//       1643.57 
//       Unable to parse '$1,643.57'. 
//       Unable to parse '-1.643e6'. 
//       -1689346178821
```